# iterating over a multidimensional array to grab specific values ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm using the Bandsintown api to grab upcoming concert dates based on which artists a user is following on my site and where the user is located.  Right now I'm having trouble iterating over a multidimensional array of data that I get back as a response.

**The Goal**

To iterate through an array of arrays and then grab an artists' name to display it on my view.

I'm able to grab the data I want with the following code inside my controller:

```
class CalendarController < ApplicationController
  require 'uri'

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @hash_version_array = []

    @user.follows.each do |follow|
      response = HTTParty.get("http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/#{URI.escape(follow.artist_name)}/events/search.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=el_proyecto_de_la_musica&location=use_geoip")
      @hash_version = JSON.parse(response.body)

      @hash_version_array << @hash_version
    end

    @hash_version_array
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

the code above produces the following results inside of my @hash_version_array (click [here](https://gist.github.com/jlquaccia/db6f0086cfa33aee9888) for the results, easier to show through a gist on github)

I get stuck when trying to iterate over @hash_version_array to grab each artist's name.

**Attempt 1**

```
[9] pry(#<CalendarController>)> @hash_version_array.each do |sub_array|
[9] pry(#<CalendarController>)*   sub_array.each do |artist|  
[9] pry(#<CalendarController>)*     artist["artists"]["name"]    
[9] pry(#<CalendarController>)*   end  
[9] pry(#<CalendarController>)* end
```

Results in

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
from (pry):96:in `[]'
```

**Attempt 2**

```
[8] pry(#<CalendarController>)> @hash_version_array.each do |sub_array|
[8] pry(#<CalendarController>)*   sub_array.each do |artist|
[8] pry(#<CalendarController>)*     artist["artists"].each do |artist|
[8] pry(#<CalendarController>)*       artist["name"]
[8] pry(#<CalendarController>)*     end  
[8] pry(#<CalendarController>)*   end  
[8] pry(#<CalendarController>)* end
```

Results in the same value I got for @hash_version_array to begin with

Comment: The reason you got that result is that `each` returns its receiver.

Comment: Your hash contains several artist's names. Do you want to extract them all to a single array?

Comment: Your question can be improved in several ways. 1. You should not provide links to data or code. If the link is broken, the question becomes incomplete for readers in future. 2. Your hash has far more keys than necessary for the purposes of the question. Boil it down to the smallest hash necessary to make your point. Show that in your question, and give it a name (e.g., `my_hash = {...}`, so readers can refer to that name in comments and answers without having to define it. 3. Show your desired output for that hash. 4. Remove the "grab the data" code if it is not relevant to your question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes I'm aiming to extract all artist names to a single array so I can use that in my view.  Also you're right my question could have been improved.  Thanks for the pointers, those are really helpful.  I'll definitely keep those in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of an artist, you'll have to fetch it via the following structure:

```
artist[0]["artists"][0]["name"]
```

I'll leave it up to you to make the code more robust.

Answer (score 0):

A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their values

```
hash = {my_key: my_value}
```

so if you want to get a `value` just use `hash['my_key']` [docs](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html)

```
  hash.each do |key,value|
      key['my_key']
    end
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.